# Accessing generic type parameters used in base class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

As I'm not sure I'm able to name/formulate everything precisely, so I would use a naive example. Let's have following:

```
class Base<T>
{
    ...
}

/*
 * Please note the Derived is not generic, only derives from generic class
 */
class Derived : Base<SomeType>
{
    /*
     * Here, I would like to use SomeType's "generic name" (like the T in the Base), 
     * so it might look like:
     */
    Base.T field1; // This would translate to 'SomeType field1' for this particular case
    ...
}
```

Is there any method in `C#` syntax how to access the `Base.T`?

*Of course I'm aware of the fact that if we make the `Derived` also generic, we can pass its type parameter to the `Base` and use it in `Derived`.*

**EDIT:**
Please consider this as a theoretical question, where I would like to determine, if there is a `C#` syntax way to reach the symbolic type names used for "templatization" in the base class. The initial motivation might be: If the developer modifies the `Derived` class the way he replaces `Base<SomeType>` by `Base<OtherType>`, he also needs to replace this in all occurences within the `Derived` body. For the cases, the `SomeType` is compatible to `OtherType` and there is also a symbolic name available (like the Base.T), there is no other work do to. (Yes, I know, we have automatic refactoring tools... Just a question...)

Comment: You are telling it what `T` is by doing `: Base<SomeType>`, so you always know what it is

Comment: Why not just use `SomeType`? It will always *be* `SomeType`, given the declaration.

Comment: What does *"use SomeType's "generic name"* mean?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Please note I'm not trying to determine it at runtime, the motivation is: if `SomeType` on the line `class Derived : Base<SomeType>` changes to `OtherType`, I would need to replace all `SomeType` occurences to `OtherType`, which is the point I wouldn't like to do.

Comment: I think you're getting a bit confused here. You're explicitly declaring the type, so why the need to refer to it implicitly (i.e. `Base.T` instead of `SomeType`)?

Comment: @sharpener - why/how would it ever change?

Comment: @JayMee: You just change your mind and want to use `OtherType`...

Comment: Then you change your `Derived` class? That's part of a development process surely? It feels like you're shooting for `Derived` to be more 'dynamic' and generic somehow, what is the actual requirement?

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov: it means instead of using the type name directly, you have "reference" to the type, which was used to templatize the base class.

Comment: @sharpener - I'm out. I can't think of a `non-hacky` way of doing this, as there's very rarely a requirement to do so. Try creating a third class inheriting from `Base<AnotherType>`, again - you've explicitly specified `AnotherType` so, *at development time*, you're clearly aware of what type it is.

Comment: If you really need to do this, you could always add another intermediate generic class to hold the field. It doesn't sound like a good idea to me though. How often are you expecting to need to change the type?

Answer (score 0):

I think that resolve your problem:

```
class Base<T> 
{
    protected T field1;
}

/*
 * Please note the Derived is not generic, only derives from generic class
 */
class Derived : Base<string> 
{
    /*
     * Here, I would like to use SomeType's "generic name" (like the T in the Base), 
     * so it might look like:
     */
    //[not necessary]
    //Base.T field1; // This would translate to 'SomeType field1' for this particular case

    public Derived()
    {
        field1 = "hello world";
    }

}
```

Comment: Sort of, but I think OP wants the member of `Derived` to be of type `T`, rather than a member of `Base`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base<T>
{
    protected T SomeField;
}

class Derived : Base<SomeType>
{
    private Type GetSomeType(bool asConstructed)
    {
        // here SomeField is SomeType because Derived is a constructed type.
        if (asConstructed)
           return SomeField.GetType(); // of course, if SomeField is null, use GetField instead

        // However, you can get the T if you really want:
        return this.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not looking for runtime type discovery. Please see the updated question.

Comment: No, there is no C# syntax for that. By reflection, you can retrieve the needed information, though.